# Can access my DNS host from external network, but not within LAN

Tags: router, dns, iptables, nat, tomato

Basically, as in title.
This is on Advanced Tomato firmware.
**NAT Loopback is configured.** Currently as "Fowrward only" (there is a port forwarding rule as well). However, was trying to put "All" and still no result.

`iptables` NAT for current "Forward only" approach:

```
iptables -n -L -v -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 873 packets, 164K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   33  1572 WANPREROUTING  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            99.99.99.99

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 77 packets, 15650 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 158 packets, 19846 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 SNAT       tcp  --  *      *       192.168.1.0/24       192.168.1.2        
 multiport dports 80,81,443 to:99.99.99.99
  402 84091 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      ppp0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain WANPREROUTING (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DNAT       icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            to:192.168.1.1
    2   120 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,81,443 to:192.168.1.2
```

`iptables` NAT for "All" approach:

```
iptables -n -L -v -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 7 packets, 668 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 WANPREROUTING  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            99.99.99.99

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 60 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 120 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    3   181 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      ppp0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      br0     192.168.1.0/24       192.168.1.0/24       to:192.168.1.1
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      br1     192.168.2.0/24       192.168.2.0/24       to:192.168.2.1
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      br2     192.168.3.0/24       192.168.3.0/24       to:192.168.3.1

Chain WANPREROUTING (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DNAT       icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            to:192.168.1.1
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,81,443 to:192.168.1.2
```

`NAT target` is set to "MASQUERADE". However, I tried "SNAT" as well with no success.

99.99.99.99 - is my masked external white (static) IP address

What could be the problem?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but seems that turning off default check on empty setting for `MultiWAN Routing Policy` helped

Comment: No. Stopped working after some time...